# my all wordpress website emails go to Spam folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I write here cause I don't know what else to do,

Recently a few days ago we move our WordPress website [caknowledge.com](https://caknowledge.com/) from siteground to AWS Ec2 Server, we setup everything and our website is running fine on AWS server.

We also install postfix for email sending but when new users signup on our website or if anyone wants to reset the password then all verification mails are going to the spam folder, we already talk to aws premium support but not getting any help from them.

Please can anyone help us, how we resolve this issue, we use PHP mailer service inbuilt in WordPress for sending emails and we already verified our domain on AWS SES.

Comment: Without the actual email headers we could only guess. There could be e.g. problems with SPF/DKIM/DMARC, an unexpected envelope sender, mismatch between the envelope sender and the `From` header, mismatch between `HELO` hostname and reverse DNS record, bad IP reputation... or the email contents may look like spam.

Comment: Please edit your question to add full headers from an email to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have [multiple SPF records](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=spf%3Acaknowledge.com&run=toolpage) - check the link to see. You can only have one SPF record according to MXToolbox, you should merge them or delete the old one.

You should also check your DKIM configuration, and check if you have any other email anti-spam technologies set up.

As Esa points out in the comments, we don't really know if this is the cause, but fixing it should help.

Comment: That's an educated and good guess, but still a guess. This could be only one of multiple problems. Unfortunately, based on this question alone we can't really know.

Comment: We know that SPF is set up incorrectly. It might not be the cause, but it's probably going to help to fix it :)

Comment: I do agree with that; it's the first thing to fix. But so many times this kind of situation only leads to a race where both the question and the answer gets updated several times and the problem remains. Just be prepared. :)

Comment: Hi we fix SPF issue but still, our mails are going in spam folder. we also check dkim and it is setup correctly and we can not have any other email anti-spam technologies